# Having a hard time understanding the context configuration (within DataSources)

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, apollo-datasource

When extending Apollo Server's `DataSources` we have to create an initialize method, inside the class :

```
initialize(config){
  this.context=config.context
}
```

Yet I cannot clearly define a mental model when it comes to the relationship between the class extension of DataSources and context.As seen in the GitHub repo of Apollo , the way to access the methods of your custom data source is by destructuring dataSource , like this:

```
getRandomData: (parent,args,{dataSource})=>{
  return dataSources.randomMethod()
}
```

Yet , how do we pass the context to Apollo Server? I thought something like this :

```
const server= new ApolloServer({
   typeDefs,
   schema,
   context,
   dataSources:()=>({...})
}
```

But if it were like this ,  `{dataSources}` destructuring does not make sense in the resolvers , so what exactly is the relationship between dataSources and context? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apollo server will [initialize `dataSources`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts#L119) within [processGraphQLRequest](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts#L104) function, it will call [dataSources.initialize()](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts#L620) method with GraphQL request context. That's why you can get the `context` object inside your custom data source `.initialize()` method. And assign `dataSources` to the `dataSources` attribute of the context, which is why you can get `dataSources` through destructuring in the GrapQL resolver.

```
  async function initializeDataSources() {
    if (config.dataSources) {
      const context = requestContext.context;

      const dataSources = config.dataSources();

      const initializers: any[] = [];
      for (const dataSource of Object.values(dataSources)) {
        if (dataSource.initialize) {
          initializers.push(
            dataSource.initialize({
              context,
              cache: requestContext.cache,
            }),
          );
        }
      }

      await Promise.all(initializers);

      if ('dataSources' in context) {
        throw new Error(
          'Please use the dataSources config option instead of putting dataSources on the context yourself.',
        );
      }

      (context as any).dataSources = dataSources;
    }
  }
}
```

The `processGraphQLRequest` function called inside [executeOperation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L997) method of [ApolloServerBase](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6954aff9b56bbb8eb0b60928df2c3e8a7941b459/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L128).